# Why doesn't this code run on Form Load, and only on button click?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I have tried form show,activate,load none work. The only way I can get this code to work is upon a button click. Is there anyway to automate the btnclick? Possibly we can figure out why this code doesn't work on form load.

A little context here, I'm have a user enter in a new job and I've loaded values entered into the previous form, to be displayed at the top of the current form. It works, just on button click. Why? Any ideas? BTW Activated below throws it into a infinite loop.

```
    Public Class Vinyl
    Dim jobnumber As Integer

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    'Collects the newely created job id from previous form
    Public Property JobID() As Integer
        Get
            Return jobnumber
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            jobnumber = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Dim dbInsert As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim dbConnect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim Line As String = Environment.NewLine
    Dim ds As New DataSet, ds2 As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter, da2 As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim PartNumber As String, PartDescription As String
    Dim PCR As Integer, run As Integer
    Dim Pdescription As Object

    Public Sub New(jobNum As Integer)
        InitializeComponent()
        jobnumber = jobNum
    End Sub

    Private Sub Vinyl_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        dbConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\crabara\Desktop\Project Alpha 3\MDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        dbConnect.Open()


        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT PartNumber,PCRNumber,Run FROM Molding WHERE JobID ='" & jobnumber & "'", dbConnect)

        da.Fill(ds, "Molding")

        PartNumber = ds.Tables("Molding").Rows(0).Item(0)
        PCR = ds.Tables("Molding").Rows(0).Item(1)
        run = ds.Tables("Molding").Rows(0).Item(2)

        lblPartNumber.Text = PartNumber
        lblPCR.Text = PCR
        lblRun.Text = run

        da2 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT PartDescription FROM PART_LIST WHERE PartNumber ='" & PartNumber & "'", dbConnect)

        da2.Fill(ds2, "PartDescription")

        PartDescription = ds2.Tables("PartDescription").Rows(0).Item(0)

        lblPartDescription.Text = Pdescription

    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeComponents()
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is the snippet of code from the previous form that is related to the jobnumber variable.

```
 JobId2 = ds3.Tables("JobID").Rows(0).Item(0)

    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "JobID"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("JobID").Value = JobId2


    'Add Values into Vinyl DB
    dbInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Molding(PartNumber,PCRNumber,Run,JobNo,JobID) VALUES(txtPart.Text,pcr,run,txtJobNo.Text,JobId2);"
    dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect
    dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'Loads the newly created jobid into the vinyl form
    myForm2.JobID = JobId2
    myForm2.Show()
```

Comment: Infinite loop? what is looping here?

Comment: Nothing, but when I ran this the try catch msgbox kep coming up. It would not go away I had to end the process. That really isn't the point though.

Comment: The MessageBox takes the focus away from the form, so when you click OK on the messagebox, guess what?  Your form is activated again.  MessageBoxes are not good debugging tools.  And obviously, FormActivated is the wrong place for this code.  Override the OnLoad method is probably more appropriate.

Comment: oh because everytime you click OK on your popup, the popup goes away and the form is reactivated and the whole code runs again. I see.

Comment: You aren't closing your database connections either.  Learn to wrap those up in a `Using...End Using` block.  "Didn't work" isn't telling you what happened, so try examining the ex.ToString information to see what the error is.

Comment: Yea, I understand why the loop was happening, that isn't the point. Why wouldn't this code run, on Vinyl_Load? Upon the load even this code is ignored, it never runs. Why?

Comment: It doesn't crash my program and the only error I get is this "A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Comment: Sounds like a 64-bit problem.  Try changing the Target CPU to x86.  IndexOutOfRange would mean the DataTable is empty since you are referring to a row or a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: That sound plausible, how would I do that?

Comment: My Project - Compile - Target CPU

Comment: I think it is x86 I don't see target cpu but I do see a Platform: Active (x86)

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured this out.  You are relying on the JobNumber variable in your code, but that looks like it isn't set until after the form is loaded.  Since it's zero, your queries are coming back empty and since your code is simply *assuming* there are records, you get an exception when you try to access a row or a column that doesn't exist.

If the JobNumber variable is critical to the form, try passing it through the constructor:

```
Public Sub New(jobNum As Integer)
  InitializeComponent()
  jobnumber = jobNum
```

Comment: Warning 3 'Public Sub New(jobNum As Integer)' in designer-generated type 'WindowsApplication1.Vinyl' should call InitializeComponent method.

Comment: Trying too, I'm getting this error on the New, I'll update my code so you can see what I'm doing.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having the same issue. Maybe I didn't call the initialize compenent right? The Jobnumber is coming the other form so it is how I'm keep a consistency here is the snippet of code form the other form regarding job number. I'll add it to my code up top

Comment: @Crabara Your making a moving line of issues for me.  Your new update to your question has a completely invalid INSERT query with those parameter names.  Let's just focus on the question at hand.  When you call your code that opens this form, what is the value of JobNumber when the code is selecting information from the database?

Comment: It is different every time, but it increments by one. Also I'm not trying to add more questions, just trying to give most information possible. I don't have any other questions.

Comment: @Crabara Your myForm2 seems to already exist, so passing the JobNumber through the constructor is too late.  Try `Dim f As New Vinyl(jobNum)` followed by `f.Show()`.  You obviously added the empty `Public Sub New()` method to fix an error you got, but that just avoided using this code.

Comment: Where should I add that code snippet? To the empty Public Sub New?

Comment: @Crabara No, I'm trying to get your to kill your myForm2 variable and replace it with that.

Comment: That didn't work, but I see your line of reasoning, because this is all taking place as the form loads, the variable never has a chance to have a value loaded to it.

Comment: Is there a way to delay the form loading, perhaps have the form click the button?

Comment: @Crabara You don't need the form loading, form shown, and definitely not form activated events. If you have the JobNum value coming through the constructor, you can just use it to do your database calls from within the constructor now.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm confused. If you get a minute later, would you happen to have a code example? I'm new to this and I'm not sure what a constructor is.

Comment: The constructor is the public sub New() I take it and I should do the db calls through that. I'm almost off my shift, I will have to pick this up on monday. I will be checking periodically over the weekend though.

Comment: @Crabara The constructor is the `Public Sub New` code block.  The InitializeComponent is a required call because it calls that method in the designer file, which is where the form designer keeps all the information for the controls that you placed on your form.  Basically, I want you to get rid of the empty constructor `Public Sub New()` so that you only have the parameterized `Public Sub New(jobNum As Integer)`.  Any errors you get in your code are places where in your code you are inappropriately creating that form since you don't have a JobNumber value yet.

Comment: Ok, I will attack that monday. I so greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Hey lars, I got the code to go through the constructor, however, I still can't get it to work now unless I have a msgbox in the code. I was hoping you could take a look at it. I posted a question again.